# Ajax doesn't append

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I having problem in creating a "see more" option using ajax.My html code is as follow

```
    <body>
//this page is index.jsp
        <%
            System.out.println("here in class");
            ClassA class_object = new ClassA();
            List list = class_object.getListValue();//gives me 6 random values
        %>

        <div id="div1">

            <div id="div2">

                <%
                    if (list != null) {
                        int count = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                        %>
                            <div class="value">
                                <%=list.get(i)%>
                            </div>
                        <%
                            count++;
                        }
                        %>

                        <a  href="#" class="see_more" onClick="load();">see more</a>

                        <%
                    }
                %>

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

on clicking see more option following function is called

```
function load()
            {
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        alert("yahoo");
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","index.jsp",true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
```

So after the ajax call new data should be attached at the end of previous data ie at the end of div class="value".I am weak in javascript so all i can do is upto this.I need suggestion along with codes.Thnks in advance.

I am posting java class code too in case required..

```
public class ClassA {


    public List getListValue()
    {
        List list = new ArrayList();

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
        int data= (int) (Math.random()*100);
        list.add("data "+data);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, how do you know that it doesnt work? Maybe the result is exactly equal to the original content. Further, I'm not sure if you should put the `setRequestHeader` before the `open()`. You should at least look in your console to look for errors.

Comment: Hello..ajax is working correctly but i dont have any idea of how to append the new content below the previous content.I am a begineer in javascript so i need help along with codes.

Comment: +1 for trying AJAX in native JS instead of using jQuery for example, but -1 for writing JAVA code directly within a JSP file... so +-0 `^^`

Comment: how can we tell you how to append something if we don't know what it is you get back from that ajax call?

Comment: The ajax function calls the same index.jsp page.I have posted the code of the same page.If you need java class code i will upload that too.Please if you have further questions ask me.I need to solve it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other developers i solved this problem using JQuery.I hope it will help to those in need.

Index.jsp code is as follow

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>


        <div id="div1">

            <div id="div2">


            </div>
            <a  href="#" class="see_more">see more</a>

        </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        loadContent = function() {
         $.ajax({
            url: "getContent.jsp",

            success: function(ret){$("#div2").append(ret)}
          });   
        }

        loadContent();

        $('.see_more').click(function(){
            loadContent();
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

getContent.jsp code is as follow

```
<%

    System.out.println("here in class");
    ClassA class_object = new ClassA();
    List list = class_object.getListValue();//gives me 6 random values

    if (list != null) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {%>
    <div class="value">
        <%=list.get(i)%>

    </div>
<%
                        count++;
                    }
    }


%>
```

ClassA code is as follow

```
import java.util.*;

public class ClassA {


    public List getListValue()
    {
        List list = new ArrayList();

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
        int data= (int) (Math.random()*100);
        list.add("data "+data);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

This way you seperate things. You give the action a proper name `seeMore`,  the ajax functionality is reusable for possible other purposes, and so is the `appendDataToBody` function.

```
function seeMore() {

    doAjaxRequest( appendDataToElem ); 
}

function doAjaxRequest( callback )
{
    var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");    // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari : IE6, IE5

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if ( callback && xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 )
        {
            callback( xmlhttp.responseText );
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open( "GET", "index.jsp", true );
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function appendDataToElem( data ) {

    document.body.innerHTML += data;
}
```

With obviously

```
<a  href="#" class="see_more" onClick="seeMore();">see more</a>
```

Comment: Instead of appending new 6 values it appends undefined to the div.

Comment: Well I didnt test this, but for debugging purposes write `console.dir(xmlhttp)` in the `if` function, to see what is returned by the ajax call